# Process Smart Target tags

Tags: smarttarget, jsp

Can you please provide some pointers on how to process the Smart target tags in a JSF application using the Tag Libraries and TLD files of Smart Target. We are using XHTML pages instead of JSP.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using JSP or ASP.NET, you might be better off using REL instead of trying to use the tags. When using REL, the web service will render everything and just return the resulting HTML.

For information on how to work with REL in SmartTarget, see the following section of the documentation: [SmartTargetTarget TCDL tag reference (REL)](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-100BAD33-2844-4816-AB8C-63F22643839A)